# ASP.NET Core Check validation based on another property with attribute

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core

My Issue is that i have a Model called DocumentType

```
Type 1 - pdf only
Type 2 - excel only
```

User must select a type and a file to upload.

Now I want to do some custom validation to check the extension associated with the type of the file but i can't seem to access the DocumentType Property in Document

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public byte[] FileBytes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(65)]
    [MaxLength(65)]
    public string ContentType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(100)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    [Display(Name = "Observações")]
    public string Observacoes { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Tipo Documento")]
    public int DocumentTypeId { get; set; }
    public DocumentType DocumentType { get; set; }

    public int ArtigoId { get; set; }
    public Artigo Artigo { get; set; }
}
```

on my page i have these properties

```
[BindProperty]
public Document Document { get; set; }  
[Required]
[BindProperty]
[MaxFileSize(3 * 1024 * 1024)]
[CheckExtension]
public IFormFile File { get; set; }
```

and this is the validation attribute where i will check extensions

```
public class CheckExtension : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var file = value as IFormFile;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);

       // TODO

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to add `IFormFIle` property do `Document` and apply validation attribute to a class

```
[CheckExtension]
public class Document
{
    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }

    public DocumentTypo DocumentType { get; set; }

    //...
}
```

And change attribute's code to

```
public class CheckExtension : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var document = value as Document;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(document.FormFile.FileName);
        // TODO

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

If you cannot or don't want to modify `Document` class you can create a wrapper class instead holding a document and a file

```
[CheckExtension]
public class DocumentWrapper
{
    public Document Document { get; set; }

    public IFormFile FormFile { get; set; }
}
```

And update attribute

```
public class CheckExtension : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var document = value as DocumentWrapper;
        var extension = Path.GetExtension(document.FormFile.FileName);
        // TODO

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

}
```